# Select column by header text and check if rest of column is empty, delete if empty?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I have an excel sheet with a similar format to the table below, if I know the column header text "Col2" how can I then check all the cells in that column only are empty or not and delete the entire column if they are?

```
*Col1 * Col2 * Col3*
********************
*Val  *      * Val *
*Val  *      * Val *
```

I think I need to select the headers in a range and find the index of the column with a header that matches the string in question and I also need to use CountA to count the not empty cells? I think there's also a step in the middle missing to select the column for CountA, then I need to delete if there are 0 not empty cells.

My working code below to open the worksheet and resize the columns:

```
            excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;

            excelBook = excelBooks.Open("test.csv", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
            Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            excelSheet = excelBook.Worksheets[1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

            excelCols = excelSheet.Columns;


            i = 1;
            while (i < colCount) {
                excelCol = excelCols[i] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range;
                excelCol.AutoFit();
            }

            //range for first row
            excelRows = excelSheet.Rows;
            excelRow = excelRows[1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range;
```

Can someone please help with this, I tried many times but I'm not totally sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, add the following `using` directive to the top of your file:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Assuming your column headers are in row 1, you could use the following method:

```
static void DeleteColumnIfEmpty(Worksheet wkst, int colNo)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= wkst.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (wkst.Cells[i, colNo].Value2 != null) return;
    }

    wkst.Columns[colNo].Delete();
}
```

And call it like this:

```
i = 1;
while (i < colCount)
{
    excelCol = excelCols[i] as Range;
    excelCol.AutoFit();

    if (excelSheet.Cells[1, i].Value2 == "Col2")
        DeleteColumnIfEmpty(excelSheet, i);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'm having a bit of a problem with if (excelSheet.Cells[1, i].Value == "Col2") - 'object' does not contain a definition for value. The same with .Value2 and .Delete

Comment: Hmm you might need to cast to Range like this: `if(((Range)excelSheet.Cells[1, i]).Value2 == "Col2")`. But I've worked pretty extensively with this library and never needed to do that. The only other thing I do differently than what's in your code above is I just write `Worksheet excelSheet = excelBook.Worksheets[1]`. I don't really know how that would change anything but might be worth a try.

Comment: Glad I could help. In terms of me saying I never have to cast to `Range`, I suspect it's because I use an older version of the library (I think v14 - I still have Office 2010). You're likely using v15.

Comment: I am indeed. Thanks for explaining that, good for me to know.